# Concurrent checking if collection is empty

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this piece of code:

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Interval> intervals = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
@Override
public void run(){
  while(!intervals.isEmpty()){
    //remove one interval
    //do calculations
    //add some intervals
  }
}
```

This code is being executed by a specific number of threads at the same time. As you see, loop should go on until there are no more intervals left in the collection, but there is a problem. In the beginning of each iteration an interval gets removed from collection and in the end some number of intervals might get added back into same collection.

Problem is, that while one thread is inside the loop the collection might become empty, so other threads that are trying to enter the loop won't be able to do that and will finish their work prematurely, even though collection *might* be filled with values after the first thread will finish the iteration. I want the thread count to remain constant (or not more than some number n) until all work is really finished.

That means that no threads are currently working in the loop and there are no elements left in the collection. What are possible ways of accomplishing that? Any ideas are welcomed.

One way to solve this problem in my specific case is to give every thread a different piece of the original collection. But after one thread would finish its work it wouldn't be used by the program anymore, even though it could help other threads with their calculations, so I don't like this solution, because it's important to utilize all cores of the machine in my problem.

This is the simplest minimal working example I could come up with. It might be to lengthy.

```
public class Test{   
   private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Interval> intervals = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
   private int threadNumber;
   private Thread[] threads;
   private double result;

   public Test(int threadNumber){
      intervals.add(new Interval(0, 1));
      this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
      threads = new Thread[threadNumber];
   }

   public double find(){
      for(int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++){
         threads[i] = new Thread(new Finder());
         threads[i].start();
      }
      try{
         for(int i = 0; i < threadNumber; i++){
            threads[i].join();
         }
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e){
         System.err.println(e);
      }
      return result;
   }   

   private class Finder implements Runnable{   
      @Override
      public void run(){
         while(!intervals.isEmpty()){
            Interval interval = intervals.poll();
            if(interval.high - interval.low > 1e-6){    
               double middle = (interval.high + interval.low) / 2;
               boolean something = true;
               if(something){
                  intervals.add(new Interval(interval.low + 0.1, middle - 0.1));
                  intervals.add(new Interval(middle + 0.1, interval.high - 0.1));
               }
               else{
                  intervals.add(new Interval(interval.low + 0.1, interval.high - 0.1));
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private class Interval{
      double low;
      double high;
      public Interval(double low, double high){
         this.low = low;
         this.high = high;
      }
   }
}
```

What you might need to know about the program: After every iteration interval should either disappear (because it's too small), become smaller or split into two smaller intervals. Work is finished after no intervals are left. Also, I should be able to limit number of threads that are doing this work with some number n. The actual program looks for a maximum value of some function by dividing the intervals and throwing away the parts of those intervals that can't contain the maximum value using some rules, but this shouldn't really be relevant to my problem.

Comment: What is ``intervals``?

Comment: Please post more code (preferrably a minimal working example) if you'd like to get good answers.

Comment: I have added the definition of intervals collection in the code.

Comment: You say "In the beginning of each iteration an interval gets removed from collection and in the end one or more intervals get added back into same collection," which seems to imply that the collection will never become empty if no threads are in the loop. Yet your code suggests that you want the program to terminate once the collection is empty and there are no threads in the loop. I suggest you clarify this point.

Comment: I've added some more code. Sorry, I didn't mean to say that. What I mean to say is that there is possibility for more intervals to appear not that they would certainly appear

Comment: I don't get the idea behind your code: It is doing nothing but splitting up intervals into smaller once, until the intervals are very very small (1e-6), in which case they are removed until the list is empty. What is all about?

Comment: Actual code is too math-intense, I don't want to boggle your mind with not important parts of the program, but I couldn't really think of a better example quickly enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use atomic flag, i.e.:

```
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Interval> intervals = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private AtomicBoolean inUse = new AtomicBoolean();

@Override
public void run() {
    while (!intervals.isEmpty() && inUse.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        // work
        inUse.set(false);
    }
}
```

UPD

Question has been updated, so I would give you better solution. It is more "classic" solution using blocking queue;

```
private BlockingQueue<Interval> intervals = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Object>();
private volatile boolean finished = false;

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (!finished) {
            Interval next = intervals.take();
            // put work there
            // after you decide work is finished just set finished = true
            intervals.put(interval); // anyway, return interval to queue
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

UPD2

Now it seems better to re-write solution and divide range to sub-ranges for each thread.

Comment: Are you sure this will work when one thread decides there in no more intervals to be added and sets the flag to stop the processing while other threads are still working and might still produce new intervals for processing?

Comment: IMO it doesn't work. Lets assume there is only one Interval in the queue and we've got two threads. The first thread checks intervals (isEmpty is false), sets inUse to true, removes one element from the queue and starts expensive computations (without producing new Interval yet). The second thread checks condition and see that queue is empty so decides to exit the loop.

Comment: The check condition `!intervals.isEmpty() && inUse.compareAndSet(false, true)` is not thread-safe, because it consists of two non-synchronized reads.

Comment: After question updated I see problem in logic. Ok, I will try to suggest better solution.

Comment: I want to clear some things up. Using your approach, deciding that work is finished equals to somehow checking if:
1. there are no intervals in the collection
2. every other thread is either waiting for an interval or if it's after the loop check condition but just before trying to take an interval
How would I do that and aren't I missing something else?

Comment: Yo can take next interval, check that solution was found, set finished = true and return interval to queue. Yes, other threads also will recheck interval but after that they will exit.

Comment: Well, the only way to know that the work is finished is to know that there are no more intervals left in the collection and that no more intervals will appear in the collection. Intervals only disappear if they got too small. How could I decide that no more intervals will appear? For that I need to know that no other thread is doing any work, right? So at the end of each iteration I would have to iterate over all threads and somehow check if they are "stuck" in intervals.take() method?

Comment: >the only way to know that the work is finished is to know that there are no more intervals left - can you provide more code, how you get result of computation? I see "result" variable, but I don't see writes to this variable. I thought that you mark finished just after setting result.

Comment: Are you suggesting checking if collection is empty? That doesn't guarantee that more intervals won't be inserted after the check by other threads that are currently working.

Comment: No, I just don't understand how you get result of your program :) I think problem just in not clear definition of algorithm. If we have strong definition of result, we can code stopping of threads.

Comment: I left that part out, because it's too mathematical and too troublesome. Basically, every iteration I find the "best" value in the interval and compare it with the "best" value I currently have and exchange them if I need to. After there are no intervals left, I know that I am left with the "bestest" value of the original interval. Sorry if it sounds too abstract.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Now it seems threads can not decide to stop without coordination. I think best solution in your case is divide range to sub-ranges for each thread.

Answer (score 2):

The CompletableFuture class is also an interesting solution for these kind of tasks.
It automatically distributes workload over a number of worker threads.

```
static CompletableFuture<Integer> fibonacci(int n) {
  if(n < 2) return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(n);
  else {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
      CompletableFuture<Integer> f1 = fibonacci(n - 1);
      CompletableFuture<Integer> f2 = fibonacci(n - 2);
      return f1.thenCombineAsync(f2, (a, b) -> a + b);
    }).thenComposeAsync(f -> f);
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int fib = fibonacci(10).get();
  System.out.println(fib);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using `CompletableFuture`. Tt's even simpler: The else-part of method `fibonacci(int)` is just `return fibonacci(n - 1).thenCombineAsync(fibonacci(n - 2), Integer::sum);`

Comment: But I wanted the entire else part to run in a different thread. If I used your suggestion only the addition would run in parallel. The `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread())` statement would always print the main thread. BTW. there is a second difference. Your code is going through the "tree" of recursive calls depth-first while mine is breadth-first.

Comment: I tested it. It does compile. `thenComposeAsync(f -> f)` turns `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Integer>>` into `CompletableFuture<Integer>`

Comment: You are right. It compiles. No idea, why it didn't work for the first time when I copy-pasted it into my IDE. Sorry.

Comment: @SpiderPig While my solution IMHO is more readable for strictly recursive problems (you can grasp the problem structure from the `RecursiveAction` implementation), your implementation using `CompletableFuture` is more flexible. If you used the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Supplier, Executor)`, you could easily configure your own executor to have as many threads as you need. You could also combine spawned `CompletableFuture`s in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like a recursive one - processing one task (interval) might produce some sub-tasks (sub intervals).

For that purpose I would use `ForkJoinPool` and `RecursiveTask`:

```
class Interval {
    ...
}

class IntervalAction extends RecursiveAction {
    private Interval interval;

    private IntervalAction(Interval interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (...) {
            // we need two sub-tasks
            IntervalAction sub1 = new IntervalAction(new Interval(...));
            IntervalAction sub2 = new IntervalAction(new Interval(...));
            sub1.fork();
            sub2.fork();
            sub1.join();
            sub2.join();
        } else if (...) {
            // we need just one sub-task
            IntervalAction sub3 = new IntervalAction(new Interval(...));
            sub3.fork();
            sub3.join();
        } else {
            // current task doesn't need any sub-tasks, just return
        }
    }
}

public static void compute(Interval initial) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(new IntervalAction(initial));
    // invoke will return when all the processing is completed
}
```

Comment: This might actually work. I only need to make sure that at most n threads are doing this work (n might even be 1... not sure if this solution is possible in that case). How would I do that?

Comment: Check [`ForkJoinPool` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) and its parallelism configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I tested the following solution.

In my test example I have a queue (the equivalent of your intervals) filled with integers. For the test, at each iteration one number is taken from the queue, incremented and placed back in the queue if the new value is below 7 (arbitrary). This has the same impact as your interval generation on the mechanism.

Here is an example working code (Note that I develop in java 1.8 and I use the [Executor framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to handle my thread pool.) :

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Test {
    final int numberOfThreads;
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> availableThreadsTokens;
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> sleepingThreadsTokens;
    final ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Test test = new Test(2); // arbitrary number of thread => 2
        test.launch();
    }

    private Test(int numberOfThreads){
        this.numberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
        this.queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer>(); 
        this.availableThreadsTokens = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(numberOfThreads);
        this.sleepingThreadsTokens = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(numberOfThreads);
        this.executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    }

    public void launch() {

        // put some elements in queue at the beginning
        queue.add(1);
        queue.add(2);
        queue.add(3);

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++){
            availableThreadsTokens.add(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Start");

        boolean algorithmIsFinished = false;

        while(!algorithmIsFinished){
            if(sleepingThreadsTokens.size() != numberOfThreads){
                try {
                    availableThreadsTokens.take();
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // some treatment should be put there in case of failure
                    break;
                }
                if(!queue.isEmpty()){ // Continuation condition
                    sleepingThreadsTokens.drainTo(availableThreadsTokens);
                    executor.submit(new Loop(queue.poll(), queue, availableThreadsTokens));
                }
                else{
                    sleepingThreadsTokens.add(1);
                }
            }
            else{
                algorithmIsFinished = true;
            }
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    public static class Loop implements Runnable{
        int element;
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;
        final BlockingQueue<Integer> availableThreadsTokens;

        public Loop(Integer element, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue, BlockingQueue<Integer> availableThreadsTokens){
            this.element = element;
            this.queue = queue;
            this.availableThreadsTokens = availableThreadsTokens;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("taking element "+element);
            for(Long l = (long) 0; l < 500000000L; l++){
            }
            for(Long l = (long) 0; l < 500000000L; l++){
            }
            for(Long l = (long) 0; l < 500000000L; l++){
            }
            if(element < 7){
                this.queue.add(element+1);
                System.out.println("Inserted element"+(element + 1));
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("no insertion");
            }
            this.availableThreadsTokens.offer(1);
        }
    }   
}
```

I ran this code for check, and it seems to work properly. However there are certainly some improvement that can be made :

- sleepingThreadsTokens do not have to be a BlockingQueue, since only the main accesses it. I used this interface because it allowed a nice sleepingThreadsTokens.drainTo(availableThreadsTokens);
- I'm not sure whether queue has to be blocking or not, since only main takes from it and does not wait for elements (it waits only for tokens).
- ...

The idea is that the main thread checks for the termination, and for this it has to know how many threads are currently working (so that it does not prematurely stops the algorithm because the queue is empty). To do so two specific queues are created : availableThreadsTokens and sleepingThreadsTokens. Each element in availableThreadsTokens symbolizes a thread that have finished an iteration, and wait to be given another one. Each element in sleepingThreadsTokens symbolizes a thread that was available to take a new iteration, but the queue was empty, so it had no job and went to "sleep". So at each moment availableThreadsTokens.size() + sleepingThreadsTokens.size() = numberOfThreads - threadExcecutingIteration.

Note that the elements on availableThreadsTokens and sleepingThreadsTokens only symbolizes thread activity, they are not thread nor design a specific thread.

Case of termination : let suppose we have N threads (aribtrary, fixed number). The N threads are waiting for work (N tokens in availableThreadsTokens), there is only 1 remaining element in the queue and the treatment of this element won't generate any other element. Main takes the first token, finds that the queue is not empty, poll the element and sends the thread to work. The N-1 next tokens are consumed one by one, and since the queue is empty the token are moved into sleepingThreadsTokens one by one. Main knows that there is 1 thread working in the loop since there is no token in availableThreadsTokens and only N-1 in sleepingThreadsTokens, so it waits (.take()). When the thread finishes and releases the token Main consumes it, discovers that the queue is now empty and put the last token in sleepingThreadsTokens. Since all tokens are now in sleepingThreadsTokens Main knows that 1) all threads are inactive 2) the queue is empty (else the last token wouldn't have been transferred to sleepingThreadsTokens since the thread would have take the job).

Note that if the working thread finishes the treatment before all the availableThreadsTokens are moved to sleepingThreadsTokens it makes no difference.

Now if we suppose that the treatment of the last element would have generated M new elements in the queue then the Main would have put all the tokens from sleepingThreadsTokens back to availableThreadsTokens, and start to assign them treatments again. We put all the token back even if M < N because we don't know how much elements will be inserted in the future, so we have to keep all the thread available.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a master/worker approach then.

The master process goes through the intervals and assigns the calculations of that interval to a different process. It also removes/adds as necessary. This way, all the cores are utilized, and only when all intervals are finished, the process is done. This is also known as dynamic work allocation.

A possible example:

```
public void run(){
  while(!intervals.isEmpty()){
    //remove one interval
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        //do calculations
    });
    t.run();
    //add some intervals
  }
}
```

The possible solution you provided is known as static allocation, and you're correct, it will finish as fast as the slowest processor, but the dynamic approach will utilize all memory.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to implement this solution, because slave threads decide how many intervals to add into the collection, not the master one.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem as well. The way I solved it was to use an AtomicInteger to know what is in the queue. Before each offer() increment the integer. After each poll() decrement the integer. The CLQ has no real isEmpty() since it must look at head/tail nodes and this can change atomically (CAS).

This doesn't guarantee 100% that some thread may increment after another thread decrements so you need to check again before ending the thread. It is better than relying on while(...isEmpty())

Other than that, you may need to synchronize.